# 'Inspect Element' in Chrome is showing LESS but Firefox is showing CSS

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, inspect, code-inspection

When I am tring to inspect an element of html in Chrome it's showing the LESS file whereas Firefox is showing CSS file. (I am using Bootstrap framework)

How can I see the css reference in Chrome?

*Please see the attached screenshot below for what I mean:*

[image: CSS in FF but LESS in]

Answer (score 5):

## Disabling CSS source maps

CSS source maps are enabled by default. You can choose to enable automatic reloading of generated CSS files. (Or Disable source maps)

To disable CSS source maps :
Open DevTools Settings (small wheel button in the right corner) and click General.
Turn off Enable CSS source maps.

## References:

[Google Chrome Working with CSS Preprocessors](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/css-preprocessors)

Answer (score 2):

**The answer by @Sergey is pretty old, and Chrome has some modifications since that time, here is an update**

1. Open DevTools -> Settings (Press F12 then Press F1)

[image]

2. Disable the option `Enable CSS sources maps`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just encountered the same thing.

Turns out it is a feature in chrome to help those using SASS or LESS.

If you are not using one of these preprocessors, you can delete the `bootstrap.css.map` file and chrome will show the css file directly, same as firefox

Comment: So it's impossible to see the generated CSS unless you *delete a file*? I would be hesitant to call it a feature in that case...

Comment: @BoltClock I aggree is should be simple to turn off this feature (maybe it is somewhere), but if you are not using a preprocessor, you shouldnt have the map files in the 1st place, and if you are, then surely you want to see and edit the less/sass file not the generated css